# How to translate a word in <a title (tpl)?

Tags: i18n-l10n

How to translate the word Menu ?
`t('Menu')` (after class="tb-main-menu-button ...) doesn't work in this case.

```
<?php
if($menu_bar = render($page['menu_bar'])): ?>
<!-- MAIN NAV -->
<div id="menu-bar-wrapper" class="wrapper">
<div class="container <?php print $grid; ?>">
<div class="grid-inner clearfix">
<a title="Navigation Icon" href="javascript:void(0);" class="tb-main-menu-button responsive-menu-button">Menu</a>
<?php print $menu_bar; ?>
```

Comment: where is this snippet ( which file) ?  did you try to put `t('Menu')` in another place? are you sure you translate it ?

Comment: Did you add `<?php ?>` ?

Comment: Menu is right there after class="tb-main-menu-button responsive-menu-button"> I tried to put t('Menu') but it doesn't work in the class. What should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `<?php print t('Menu') ?>`

Like so:

```
<a title="Navigation Icon" href="javascript:void(0);" class="tb-main-menu-button responsive-menu-button"><?php print t('Menu') ?></a>
```

This will make the string translatable in the admin interface.